# How can i pass constructor args to test solidity contracts in Hardhat?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, openzeppelin-contracts, chai

I am using openzepplin with role based access control to create erc-20 token

```
constructor(address minter, address burner) ERC20("ArtPlace Token", "ARTP") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 10000000 * 10 ** decimals());
        _grantRole(MINTER_ROLE, minter);
        _grantRole(BURNER_ROLE, burner);
    }
```

how can i pass constructor arguments to test scripts for the test cases to be satisfied?

My test script looks like this:

```
import { network, getNamedAccounts, deployments, ethers} from "hardhat";
import { expect } from "chai";


describe("Token contract", function () {
  let token:ethers.Contract;
  let deployer: ethers.Signer;
  let other: ethers.Signer;


  beforeEach(async function () {

    // const [owner, addr1, addr2, ...addrs] = await ethers.getSigners();

    const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("ARTPToken");
    [deployer, other] = await ethers.getSigners();
    
     token = await Token.deploy();

    await token.deployed();
  });


  describe('Mint', () => {

    it("should allow the deployer to mint tokens", async function () {
      const amount = ethers.utils.parseEther("100");
      await token.connect(deployer).mint(other.address, amount);
      const balance = await token.balanceOf(other.address);
      expect(balance).to.equal(amount);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass all the constructor arguments to the `deploy()` function. Let's suppose that the minter should be the `addr1` account and the burner should be the `addr2` account.

Thus, update your `beforeEach()` method as follows:

```
beforeEach(async function () {

    const [deployer, addr1, addr2] = await ethers.getSigners();

    // set the minter and burner addresses
    const minter = addr1.address;
    const burner = addr2.address;

    const tokenFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("ARTPToken");
    const token = await tokenFactory.deploy(minter, burner);

    await token.deployed();

    console.log(`ARTPToken address: ${token.address}`);
  });
```